# Отступы между блоками

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как реализовать эти отступы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так это выглядит сейчас:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```css
a.links {
  color: #094f83;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  right: 30px;

}

img.linksimg {
  width: 209px;
  height: 153px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
   <a href="" class="links">Тарехова Катя</a>
   <img src="http://lfly.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/484429689.jpg" class="linksimg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
   <a href="" class="links">Тарехова Катя</a>
   <img src="http://lfly.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/484429689.jpg" class="linksimg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
   <a href="" class="links">Тарехова Катя</a>
   <img src="http://lfly.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/484429689.jpg" class="linksimg" alt="">
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: ЗЫ, делать сетку больше нельзя во избежании переноса на следующую строку.

Comment: а padding col-md-4 col-xs-12 правый прописать не подходит?

Comment: @Oleksandr сейчас не понял..